# Как получить defaultValue из EditTextPreference SharedPreferences?

Tags: java, android, android-preferences

Использую `SharedPreferences` для настроек в приложении.
Есть `EditTextPreference`, в котором установлено какое-нибудь значение по умолчанию. Как его получить теперь? (присвоить переменной)

Файл меню настроек:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/pref_user_profile" >
    <EditTextPreference
        android:title="@string/pref_user_id_summary"
        android:summary="@string/pref_user_id_description"
        android:defaultValue="@string/pref_user_id_default_value"
        android:key="prefUserId"/>
</PreferenceCategory>
```

В активити пытаюсь получить как-то так:

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    id_num = sharedPrefs.getString("prefUserId", "");
```

Во вторых кавычках, как я понимаю, устанавливается значение по умолчанию. Но это не то значение, которое в поле `defaultValue`. Как его получить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам надо перед обращением в преференсам отдельно сказать активити, чтобы она подгрузила значения по умолчанию.

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.pref_design, true);
//теперь можно получать дефолтные значения
```

Где первый аргумент - `Context`, т.е. ваша активити в вашем случае, а вместо `R.xml.pref_design` вы должны поставить `ID` вашего `xml` файла с настройками вида `R.ИМЯ_ПАПКИ_В_RES_VALUES_ГДЕ_ЛЕЖИТ_XML_ФАЙЛ.ИМЯ_XML_ФАЙЛА_СОДЕРЖАЩЕГО_НАСТРОЙКИ`

Comment: Получилось, спасибо!

Comment: @Dev_Vlad, всегда пожалуйста)